# SQL conditional rolling sum

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery Standard SQL and need to take a rolling sum of `submit_amount` by customer (`cust_id`) from my transaction table.

However, I can only include certain transactions in the rolling sum. My conditions are:

`paid_date` of the row that may need to be included in the rolling sum `IS NULL` or `>=` the `submit_date` of the row that is being calculated

`submit_date` of the row that may need to be included in the rolling sum is between 0 and 30 days prior to the `submit_date` the row that is being calculated

`cust_id` must match current row `cust_id`

Here is a sample of my data, with the `accrued_amount` field that I would like to calculate. I also added a field here just to make more clear which transactions should qualify for the rolling sum in each row.

```
txn_id | cust_id | submit_date | paid_date  | submit_amount | accrued_amount | qual_txn_id
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 |       1 |  2020-01-01 | 2020-01-15 |            10 |            10  |   1
     2 |       1 |  2020-01-12 | 2020-02-01 |             5 |            15  |   1, 2
     3 |       1 |  2020-01-25 |       NULL |             2 |             7  |   2, 3
     4 |       1 |  2020-02-05 |       NULL |             4 |             6  |   3, 4
     5 |       1 |  2020-02-06 |       NULL |             1 |             7  |   3, 4, 5
     6 |       1 |  2020-03-01 | 2020-03-15 |             3 |             8  |   4, 5, 6
     7 |       2 |  2020-03-05 | 2020-03-20 |             6 |             6  |   7
     8 |       2 |  2020-03-25 |       NULL |             2 |             2  |   8
```

I have worked out criteria #2 and #3, but am not sure how to incorporate #1.  Below is my current query:

```
SELECT 
  txn_id, cust_id, submit_date, paid_date, submit_amount,
  SUM(submit_amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY cust_id
    ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(submit_date)
    RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  AS accrued_amount
FROM t;
```

I tried using `CASE WHEN` in place of `submit_amount` (inside the `SUM()`) to apply the `paid_date` criteria, but couldn't get it to compare the right rows to each other.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: `submit_date is between 0 and 30 days prior to current row submit_date` <-- this makes no sense, please explain.  I think you have a typo.

Comment: I mean that the submit date of the row that might need to be included in the rolling sum needs to be 0-30 days before whichever row is being calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr),
    (
      SELECT SUM(IF(paid_date IS NULL OR paid_date >= submit_date, submit_amount, 0))
      FROM UNNEST(arr) 
    ) AS accrued_amount, 
    (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(IF(paid_date IS NULL OR paid_date >= submit_date, CAST(txn_id AS STRING), NULL))
      FROM UNNEST(arr) 
    ) AS qual_txn_id 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(txn_id, paid_date, submit_amount)) OVER (
      PARTITION BY cust_id 
      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(submit_date)
      RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS arr  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 txn_id, 1 cust_id, DATE '2020-01-01' submit_date, DATE '2020-01-15' paid_date, 10 submit_amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, '2020-01-12', '2020-02-01', 5, UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, '2020-01-25', NULL, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 1, '2020-02-05', NULL, 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 1, '2020-02-06', NULL, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1, '2020-03-01', '2020-03-15', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 2, '2020-03-05', '2020-03-20', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 2, '2020-03-25', NULL, 2
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr),
    (
      SELECT SUM(IF(paid_date IS NULL OR paid_date >= submit_date, submit_amount, 0))
      FROM UNNEST(arr) 
    ) AS accrued_amount, 
    (
      SELECT STRING_AGG(IF(paid_date IS NULL OR paid_date >= submit_date, CAST(txn_id AS STRING), NULL))
      FROM UNNEST(arr) 
    ) AS qual_txn_id 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(txn_id, paid_date, submit_amount)) OVER (
      PARTITION BY cust_id 
      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(submit_date)
      RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS arr  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

result is

```
Row txn_id  cust_id submit_date paid_date   submit_amount   accrued_amount  qual_txn_id  
1   1       1       2020-01-01  2020-01-15  10              10              1    
2   2       1       2020-01-12  2020-02-01  5               15              1,2  
3   3       1       2020-01-25  null        2               7               2,3  
4   4       1       2020-02-05  null        4               6               3,4  
5   5       1       2020-02-06  null        1               7               3,4,5    
6   6       1       2020-03-01  2020-03-15  3               8               4,5,6    
7   7       2       2020-03-05  2020-03-20  6               6               7    
8   8       2       2020-03-25  null        2               2               8
```

Also, below is refactored - slightly less verbose version of above one with exactly same output

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(arr),
    (
      SELECT AS STRUCT 
        SUM(IF(qual, submit_amount, 0)) AS accrued_amount,
        STRING_AGG(IF(qual, CAST(txn_id AS STRING), NULL)) AS qual_txn_id
      FROM UNNEST(arr), UNNEST([paid_date IS NULL OR paid_date >= submit_date]) qual 
    ).* 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(txn_id, paid_date, submit_amount)) OVER (
      PARTITION BY cust_id 
      ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(submit_date)
      RANGE BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS arr  
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```